# How do I avoid CORS errors when making API Gateway calls from my local machine?

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to web development, this might be a question with a simple answer, but I have been stuck on this problem for hours and can't seem to solve it.

A friend of mine is developing a pretty standard serverless web app using AWS, to which I have started to contribute. We are running python lambda functions connected to API gateway. These work fine, and pass all of my tests. I am attempting to make requests to the API with js scripts running in html files, which are currently living on my local machine.

However, when I write my js code to make API requests using the jQuery ajax function, and run the html/js in my browser on my localhost, the requests are not sent because of CORS errors, even though our API is configured to allow CORS. I have read several articles about CORS and I grasp its purpose and basic mechanics. I have also read the full jQuery ajax documentation, and reviewed HTTP requests and responses.

From what I have read, it seems that I in fact shouldn't be able to make requests from my localhost to an API hosted on AWS, since they are in fact hosted on different 'origins,' However, I am confused because my friend's code does not produce these errors, and after hours of comparing our js code, neither of us can find any meaningful differences in our scripts. We are both stumped. I found some workarounds that entail disabling various browser security features, but my friend thinks that is risky and unnecessary.

So I have two questions that I haven't been able to find clear answers to:

Should I be getting CORS errors in this situation? Is there a way to avoid them without disabling browser security settings?

More generally how do people typically develop the front-end of a web app locally while making calls to a remote API? Am I approaching this project in the wrong way?

Thank you thank you!

Comment: Can you share your cors configuration

Comment: Need you to share the errors and your approach (code).

Comment: The Allow-Access-Control-Origin header is set to "*". We did this using the AWS console.

Comment: The error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/me/mysite/perform-action-for-user' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: In short - you need to serve youe html page from a web server. The address in the url has to start with http:// or with https://     not file

Answer (score -1):

You can enable CORS on an API Gateway resource by following the [guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#how-to-cors-console). For your development environment you can set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `'*'`. This will allow you to successfully make requests from your local environment.

For higher environments, where you don't need to test locally, you should avoid allowing cross origin wildcard access. This can expose your API to potential security threats.

If you're using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) to manage your API, there's a simple guide for enabling CORS on your API Gateway endpoints in the [Serverless Blog](https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/#how-do-i-handle-preflight-requests-with-serverless).